# Segfault when trying to use external functions in assembly

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb, nasm

I am trying to create a program that calls external functions from assembly. I was following this guide https://www.devdungeon.com/content/how-mix-c-and-assembly and tried to use the code under the Calling C from Assembly section:

```
extern  printf

SECTION .DATA
    msg:    db "Hello world", 0 ; Zero is Null terminator 
    fmt:    db "%s", 10, 0 ; printf format string follow by a newline(10) and a null terminator(0), "\n",'0'

SECTION .TEXT
    global main
    
main:
    push rbp ; Push stack

    ; Set up parameters and call the C function
    mov rdi,fmt
    mov rsi,msg
    mov rax,0
    jmp printf

    pop rbp     ; Pop stack

    mov rax,0   ; Exit code 0
    ret         ; Return
```

I used `nasm test.asm -f elf64` and then `gcc test.o -no-pie -o test`
but when running it would instantly segfault.
I looked at it in gdb and it segfaults on the first instruction
 `► 0x402014       <main>                           push   rbp`
I think the culprit is that this section of code is not executable.

```
vmmap
          0x400000           0x401000 r--p     1000 0     [redacted]
          0x401000           0x402000 r-xp     1000 1000   
          0x402000           0x403000 r--p     1000 2000   
          0x403000           0x404000 r--p     1000 2000   
          0x404000           0x405000 rw-p     1000 3000
```

to further back this idea when compiling with gdb and not using the -no-pie argument I get this error message

```
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: warning: relocation in read-only section .TEXT
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5 can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Case matters. `SECTION .TEXT` should be `SECTION .text` (lower case). You got a non-executable section. Also you should `call printf` and not `jmp`. For PIE, that should really be `call printf wrt ..plt`.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I ment put call instead of jmp was just testing other things out. Thanks!